# How to convert material color palette to Flutter theme?

Tags: colors, flutter, themes, material-design

I can use https://material.io/tools/color to generate attractive color palettes. The result is a set of eight colors.

Unfortunately, the [`ThemeData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) makes it difficult to build a theme from these eight values alone. There is [a constructor](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html) that promises to derive sensible default values for missing arguments, however it doesn't derive everything from the primary and secondary colors.

Am I missing something here? Are there any Flutter tools for converting a material palette into a material theme?

Comment: Anyone got the answer yet? I have problem since Flutter naming is different

Comment: I am surprised there is no designed method to do this from https://material.io/tools/color. Only supports iOS and Android which exports in .swift or xml respectively.

Comment: Found the same issue and it is 1 year on from @Duncan's original email. The material.io/tools/color has no flutter equivalent theme generator. Anyone here found an alternative? I did find this but have not tried it yet: https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-material-theme-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In flutter, you can use **MaterialColor** for different color shades like Colors.blue[300].

Though ThemeData accepts **Color** Object as per its [constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html) but you can use **MaterialColor** with different color shades like **Colors.blue[300]** since its inherited from Color:

> (**Color** -> ColorSwatch -> MaterialColor)

**Recommendations:** 
you should not use it directly in ThemeData or anyplace where **Color** is needed since sometimes while building compiler raises the issue with a glitch of red error screen (I personally faced this issue).

For example:

```
final AppTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue[300],  //<- Not recommended
    );
```

The right solution to this issue is :

```
final AppTheme = ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue.shade300,  //<- recommended
        );
```